# Interchange positions of two buttons

Tags: c#, button, position

I want to replace button location (Interchange location )by black button when i click it and it is next to black button  (b9=black button and lable1 is a temp for saving location).

I made this method :

```
void checkLocation()
    {
        if (ActiveControl.Location == new Point(5, 7))//-----------for button 1
        {
            if (b9.Location == new Point(83, 7) || b9.Location == new Point(5, 71))
            {
                label1.Location = ActiveControl.Location;
                ActiveControl.Location = b9.Location;
                b9.Location = label1.Location;
            }
        }// it continue for every button
```

and I write this code for every button_click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       checkLocation();
    }
```

now,some button don't work currently . what is wrong ?

Comment: Please for the sake of future programmers, name your controls... And then use that name to search for a control. Otherwise what "don't work currently"

Comment: no,no,no ... I don't write all code here.Certainly i named my control.all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by thanks from p.s.w.g
I think it is shorter and fit :

```
void swapLocation()
    {
        var tmp = ActiveControl.Location;

        if((ActiveControl.Location.X==b9.Location.X)&&(Math.Abs(b9.Location.Y-ActiveControl.Location.Y)<=60))
            {
             ActiveControl.Location = b9.Location;
             b9.Location = tmp;
            }
        if ((ActiveControl.Location.Y == b9.Location.Y) && (Math.Abs(b9.Location.X-ActiveControl.Location.X) <= 70))
            {
            ActiveControl.Location = b9.Location;
            b9.Location = tmp;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this to swap the locations of two controls:

```
void swapLocation()
{
    var tmp = ActiveControl.Location;
    ActiveControl.Location = b9.Location;
    b9.Location = tmp;
}
```

Or more generally

```
void swapLocation(Control x, Control y)
{
    var tmp = x.Location;
    x.Location = y.Location;
    y.Location = tmp;
}

...
swapLocation(ActiveControl, b9);
```

---

**Update**

It looks like you're trying to implement a version of the [15-puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle). There are numerous ways to solve this, but to avoid a radical rewrite of your program I'd recommend this:

```
private int buttonWidth = 82;
private int buttonHeight = 82; // adjust these values as needed

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if ((Math.Abs(ActiveControl.Location.X - b9.Location.X) == 0 &&
        Math.Abs(ActiveControl.Location.Y - b9.Location.Y) == buttonHeight) ||
       (Math.Abs(ActiveControl.Location.X - b9.Location.X) == buttonWidth &&
        Math.Abs(ActiveControl.Location.Y - b9.Location.Y) == 0))
   {
       swapLocation(ActiveControl, b9);
   }
}
```

This basically checks to see if the `ActiveControl` is either directly above, below, to the left, or the right of `b9`, and if it is, swaps them. You can use this click handler for all buttons 1 through 8. Note this method ***only*** works with the buttons are a fixed width and height.

Comment: i find my answer, but i can't write here for 8 hours after asking . now a question . in this puzzle , how i can set button randomly ?

Comment: @Majid I'm not sure, but I believe with this kind of puzzle, if you just randomly place the buttons, you're likely end up with an unsolvable puzzle. Since this answer solved your original issue I suggest you read up a bit more on the 15-puzzle (or the smaller 8-puzzle variant you're working on), try something out, and come back here when you run into a problem. Heck SO even has a tag for it: [tag:8-puzzle].

Comment: you help me very much .tnx